# Is there a way to reduce the heap size of threads in C language?

Tags: c, pthreads, heap-memory

[massif diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kapYs.png)

I used Valgrind's Massif feature to check the memory usage of my C language program to investigate memory usage.
I had many dynamic allocations in my code, but according to Massif, I found that it was consistently using the same amount of memory.
Upon further investigation, I discovered that my program uses two threads, and each thread consistently allocates 64MB of heap memory.

According to the attached diagram, it can be observed that when two threads were initially created, they used 150.3MB of memory. When one thread was terminated, there was a precise reduction of 64MB, resulting in 86.3MB of memory usage.

I don't perform dynamic allocations that would justify the need for 64MB of heap memory. This seems like a complete waste

Does creating threads in C language inherently lead to using a fixed 64MB of heap memory? Is there a way to reduce the heap memory allocated to threads?

OS: Ubuntu 22.04

I tried adjusting the stack size, but it was naturally ineffective.
I want to reduce the 64MB of heap memory allocated to threads.

Comment: What amount of heap memory _do_ you use then, if any? We can't really speculate in what part of your code that takes up x amount of bytes without seeing the code.

Comment: Since Linux does lazy allocation, why do you care? Real pages will be allocated only if you actually use them. The biggest component of per-thread storage is its stack.

Comment: There are many reasons code can use a lot of memory.  You haven't demonstrated how or why your code is using more memory than you think it should.  No one can answer your question and tell you how to reduce your code's memory usage without knowing how your code is using memory.  The creation of two threads isn't by itself going to use a total 128 MB of RAM.

Comment: Ideally, you need to edit your question and add as much code as necessary to demonstrate the problem.  How your code is started and the environment it runs in, and the resource limits your program is using could also be important.  The command `ulimit -a` will show the soft limits for the shell you run it under, but your program can run under different limits.

Comment: @stark I will be using it in an embedded system later, and there are very strict RAM usage limits. I was surprised to see Valgrind reporting excessive memory usage. Based on what you're saying, does it mean that if Valgrind reports 150MB of memory usage, it may not actually be using that much memory?

Comment: It shouldn't be too difficult to cobble up a minimal C program which creates two threads that do nothing, and measure its heap usage.

Comment: Your explanation was correct. I have learned that heap memory allocation varies using the C program. Thank you @n.m.couldbeanAI

Comment: I've learned that the heap size varies depending on the code. Thank you all. I will attempt to re-engineer my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example to show that it isn't the creation of the pthreads that takes up all that space. Your threads must have there own memory allocations associated with them. In that case you may need to re-engineer your program to use memory more efficiently, if that's possible.

With this program I can easily create 10,000+ threads without even a 1GB bump in memory usage.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

// gcc threadmemtest.c -o threadmemtest.bin -O3 -Wall -pthread -march=native

void* sleepforabit(void*arg) {
  sleep(25);
  return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  int i, numthreads = 5;
  if (argc > 1) numthreads = atoi(argv[1]);  
  pthread_t *threadid = malloc(numthreads*sizeof(pthread_t));
  for (i=0; i<numthreads; i++) {
    if (pthread_create(&threadid[i], NULL, sleepforabit, NULL) != 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Error creating pthread[%i].\n", i);
      numthreads = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  for (i=0; i<numthreads; i++) {
    pthread_join(threadid[i], NULL);
  }
  free(threadid);
  pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Comment: It's possible the OP's code creates the threads using a non-`NULL` `pthread_attr_t` with a larger stacksize set with [`pthread_attr_setstacksize()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/pthread_attr_setstacksize.html).  The question really needs a lot more details.

Comment: Please add the Massif total as OP did.

Comment: @stark That would be useful, but I don't think it's necessary.  [The default thread stack size on x86_64 Linux is only 2 MB](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html), strongly implying the OP's code that uses 64 MB per thread is doing a lot more than default thread creation.  Those details need to be added to the question.

Comment: I was able to confirm that a thread allocates heap memory as needed through your code, and Valgrind reported a total usage of 40MB. Thank you.